# Do I need to define all classes as Magento models?

Tags: php, magento

I am defining a new block to clean up my view like so:

```
class Jamie_Utilities_Block_Myblock extends Mage_Core_Block_Template
{
    public function getProducts()
    {
        $products = array(
            new Product('Product Name', "image source"),
            new Product('Product Name', "image source"),
        );
        return $products;
    }
}
```

I would like to create a little `Product` class in the same file to hold a couple fields. Myblock.php now looks like:

```
class Jamie_Utilities_Block_Myblock extends Mage_Core_Block_Template
{...}

class Product
{
    public $name;
    public $image;

    public function __construct($name, $image)
    {
        $this->name  = $name;
        $this->image = $image;
    }
}
```

This works, but is it a good thing to do? Should I be declaring all my classes as models in the module's `config.xml` or should I just use a better class name to avoid conflicts e.g. `Jamie_Utilities_Block_Product`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `<models>` node in your config is a class *prefix*, not a class name.

An example config of `<config><global><models><your_module><class>Yer_Module_Model</class></...>` is what's found when this code is parsed: `Mage::getModel('your_module/rest_of_class_name');`.  The first part is converted to yer_module_model, and the rest is tacked on with a leading underscore, i.e. `yer_module_model_rest_of_class_name`. According to the autoloader, the system will look for that definition in `Yer/Module/Model/Rest/Of/Classname.php`.

The short story is this: define your class prefix and you can create as many classes as you want.

Comment: For some reason I had thought I needed to explicitly mention each model. Thanks.